# What is the data type for these jwt claims

Tags: jwt, bearer-token

I am trying to find the correct data type or encryption type for the claims in a jwt. ("profile") I'm looking to find the data type / encryption type to enable me create new variables for sub & profile claim in the jwt.
"profile":"1A78C8FB054EC91107C6A22C306F45153F409B32BFD5141977FE79072257B2149699A7EBD263F49C57CE1AFED0E23B91F2F71CB23531B0BEF0E27D0BA16DE6ED"}

Comment: most standard claims that are not representing timesstamps (e.g. exp) are just strings with no special format (see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1). *sub* is such a standard claim, *profile* is a custom claim. The standard doesn't say anything about the content. In your case both look like hex encoded.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I have tried to decode the strings (sub & profile ) using a hex decoder but i did not get a meaningful data returned.

Comment: What do you mean by "data type"? Both values look like strings to me

Comment: You will have to ask the creator of that token. Most claims (unless explicitly specified otherwise) don't have any specific format or semantics, and everbody can put in there whatever he wants ...

Comment: The values are not strings, I was able to confirm to an extent that the values are HEX encoded. I think that the server is generating the data by encoding a string value or integer (probably user email or phone number) to produce the value of sub & profile.

Comment: I did some more digging and the values for the profile & sub claims seem to be SHA512 encrypted with 128 bits. Is there any known working method to decode/decrypt SHA512??

Comment: SHA is a hashing algorihtm. If there was any way of breaking it, you would not be using it ;)

Comment: hashes are one-way: https://www.techsolvency.com/passwords/dehashing-reversing-decrypting/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a lot of research alas after all the digging i found out it was an integer hashed to SHA512. Thanks to everyone that gave a tip. Y'all great, this article helped alot too ..

https://medium.com/@zaid960928/cryptography-explaining-sha-512-ad896365a0c1